# Minecraft is not rendering far

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Why is minecraft not rendering more than about 12 chunks?
Singleplayer not on a server.

I have tried allowing minecraft to use more ram but no effect.

Maybe because i dont have a graphics card?
Minecraft is only using about 30-40% of graphics in task manager.

Comment: Whats your render distance set to in the video settings?

Comment: Even if it's set higher, it might just take a while. Try waiting for multiple minutes without moving much.

Answer (score 1):

Check your render distance in your Video Settings sub-menu settings options. It'll show as a slider on the top-right corner of the settings list. Increase it by dragging the bar to the right to increase the render distance

[image]